# How to define enum type in beego orm model?

Tags: postgresql, go, orm, beego

How do I define an enum type in my beego orm model?

I tried:

model.go

```golang
type User struct {
    Id              string         `json:"id" orm:"pk;"`
    Gender          Gender         `json:"gender" orm:"type(gender)" default:"X"`
}

type Gender string

const (
    GenderX     Gender = "X"
    GenderMan   Gender = "MAN"
    GenderWomen Gender = "WOMEN"
)

func (e *Gender) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    *e = Gender(value.(string))
    return nil
}

func (e Gender) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return string(e), nil
}

func (e Gender) String() string {
    return string(e)
}
```

The enum does exist in the database already.

Answer (score 0):

In Beego, enum doesn't exist. You can define in database as enum.

```
gender enum('X', 'WOMAN', 'MAN')default('X')
```

And the model definition should be like that.

```
type User struct {
    Id              string         `json:"id" orm:"pk;"`
    Gender          Gender         `json:"gender" orm:"size(25);default(X)"`
}
```